# Помогите, плиз, с REGEXP в PHP

Tags: php, python, регулярные-выражения

Уважаемое сообщество! Уже который час я кручу эту регулярку, никак не могу добиться нужного результата. Нужна помощь знатоков.
Есть такая строка:

**emailAddress = uc_fk@roskazna.ru, ST = г. Москва, INN = 007710568760, OGRN = 1047797019830, street = "Большой Златоустинский переулок, д. 6, строение 1", L = Москва, C = RU, O = Федеральное казначейство, CN = Федеральное казначейство**

Мне нужно выкусывать значение поля, например, CN=???? или street=????

Кусаю так: **preg_match('/O\s?=\s?"?(.+)"?,/i', $line);**

O= — выкусывает хорошо, но с конечным условием - беда, поэтому другие кусает неправильно.

Что я там не дописал?

Comment: Я, как человек, у которого туг с регулярными сделал бы проще. Если структура всегда одинаковая, пробежался бы по строке, заменив все emailAddress = ... , CN = на какой-нибудь символ и потом explode()

Comment: Спасибо, дружище! Совершенно простой и правильный совет. Я почему-то зациклился на волшебстве регулярных выражений и не увидел простого выхода.
Конечно! Сделать explode(), а потом распознать как следует!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```php
$re = '/(\w+)\s*=\s*(?|"([^"]*)"|([^,]*))/u';
$str = 'emailAddress = uc_fk@roskazna.ru, ST = г. Москва, INN = 007710568760, OGRN = 1047797019830, street = "Большой Златоустинский переулок, д. 6, строение 1", L = Москва, C = RU, O = Федеральное казначейство, CN = Федеральное казначейство';

if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    $arr = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
    print_r($arr);
}
```

То же, но на Python:

```py
import re
rx = '(\w+)\s*=\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|([^,]*))'
text = 'emailAddress = uc_fk@roskazna.ru, ST = г. Москва, INN = 007710568760, OGRN = 1047797019830, street = "Большой Златоустинский переулок, д. 6, строение 1", L = Москва, C = RU, O = Федеральное казначейство, CN = Федеральное казначейство'

matches = [(x.group(1),x.group(3)) if x.group(3) else (x.group(1),x.group(2)) for x in re.finditer(rx, text)]
print( dict(matches) )
```

См. [пример работы кода PHP](https://3v4l.org/WfoL8) и на [Python](https://ideone.com/VGskLL). Результат:

```
Array
(
    [emailAddress] => uc_fk@roskazna.ru
    [ST] => г. Москва
    [INN] => 007710568760
    [OGRN] => 1047797019830
    [street] => Большой Златоустинский переулок, д. 6, строение 1
    [L] => Москва
    [C] => RU
    [O] => Федеральное казначейство
    [CN] => Федеральное казначейство
)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/GHGpUA/2).

*Подробности*:

- `(\w+)` - Группа №1: один и более букво-цифровых символов, а также символов нижнего подчёркивания
- `\s*=\s*` - `=`, заключённый в ноль и более пробельных символов
- `(?|` - начало группы со сбросом индексов захватывающих групп

  - `"([^"]*)"` - `"`, группа №2, захватывающая ноль и более символов, отличных от `"`, а затем `"`
- `|` - или

  - `([^,]*)` - Группа №2 (всё ещё №2): один и более символов, отличных от запятой
- `)` - конец группы со сбросом индексов захватывающих групп.

Comment: Супер! Спасибо, дружище! Именно об этой магии регулярок я и мечтал!

Comment: Отдельное спасибо за Python!
Я уже как-то выкрутился, но вот это изящное питоновское: "[(x.group(1),x.group(3)) if x.group(3) else (x.group(1),x.group(2)) for x in re.finditer(rx, text)]" просто потрясает

Comment: @anthony3d Раз вам так нравятся регулярные выражения, посмотрите [этот пример кода](https://tio.run/##lVE9TwJBEO35FZNruMXN5c4PDgqjxsKYGExQK0BDYNGLckf2lngaC9FCCxsrG0t/wAUhgsTzL8z9onMWtbC02MzMm/dmXnZ6F@ok8JeyzOv2AqlAimMR5WQEq5A36@cLrB4WVumZa1eGWTs0GgVmXFHCKWH5nBKR0lTRbXpnG@22FGFIdb911Dldl0F42rz0m5bsc9jbJxxfLcBnTNIBvuMQYw7blQrhtu26jr1SLLlFm8PuVlWDjr3sumXXdsqlJUJDJYXQywx8xARn6UN6T3EK@IQzjNMbGnubDihO8GO@YKKbnzhOr@ndEinBdw44sqDIQTOpkeAYP4g5BsfgsKM9/vG3SUj1gDzpzguRR/N5sd5PQpIDUWN8oyJO74gwnXsYYkLiyv9V@Vy3qVonQn9jzYysYxn0e6bD@G@6yBh0AgkReP73uayO57c9JaQpIw76JKyR60nPVya0vZYyfyYyYFn2BQ).

Comment: Ну, здесь даже понятней, без if'а. А зачем он был там?

Comment: @anthony3d В примере, который я только что привёл, используется модуль PyPi `regex` (устанавливается с помощью `pip install regex` в консоли), он позволяет использовать регулярки PCRE в Python (ну, многие его примочки).

Comment: Вот, нельзя тут просто говорить "Спасибо", но я очень благодарен за этот код. Постараюсь его изучить и понять.